How to show that $\partial x^\sigma / \partial x_\nu = g^{\nu\sigma}$?
I just want to confirm that $$\frac{\partial x^\sigma}{\partial x_\nu} = g^{\nu\sigma} .$$
You cannot proceed directly:
$$\frac{\partial x^\sigma}{\partial x_\nu} = \frac{\partial (g^{\rho\sigma} x_\rho)}{\partial x_\nu} = g^{\rho\sigma} \frac{\partial x_\rho}{\partial x_\nu} + x_\rho \frac{\partial g^{\rho\sigma}}{\partial x_\nu} = g^{\nu\sigma} + x_\rho \frac{\partial g^{\rho\sigma}}{\partial x_\nu}$$
because you're stuck with what appears to be an extra term (and anyway $x_\rho$ isn't a vector!).
On the other hand, write
$$dx_\sigma = \frac{\partial x_\sigma}{\partial x^\alpha} dx^\alpha \quad\quad dx_\nu = \frac{\partial x_\nu}{\partial x^\beta} dx^\beta$$
so $$ds^2 = g^{\sigma\nu}dx_\sigma dx_\nu = g^{\sigma\nu}\frac{\partial x_\sigma}{\partial x^\alpha} \frac{\partial x_\nu}{\partial x^\beta} dx^\alpha dx^\beta = g_{\alpha\beta}dx^\alpha dx^\beta $$
so that
$$g^{\sigma\nu}\frac{\partial x_\sigma}{\partial x^\alpha} \frac{\partial x_\nu}{\partial x^\beta} = g_{\alpha\beta} .$$
Since
$$g^{\sigma\nu}g_{\sigma\alpha}g_{\nu\beta} = g_{\alpha\beta} $$
we have
$$\frac{\partial x_\sigma}{\partial x^\alpha} \cdot \frac{\partial x_\nu}{\partial x^\beta} = g_{\sigma\alpha} \cdot g_{\nu\beta}$$
and the original assertion seems to be true (sorry, flip all the indices). Is there a more direct proof?

Oh, maybe it's this simple. Compare the two equations:
$$dx^\rho = \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial x_\sigma}dx_\sigma$$
$$dx^\rho = g^\rho_\sigma dx^\sigma = g^{\rho\sigma} dx_\sigma$$
The result follows!

Hi Khun Chang. How are the undifferentiated variables $x^\rho$ and $x_\sigma$ defined/related according to you?

By the equation I gave above: $dx^\rho = g^{\rho\sigma}dx_\sigma$.

These differential relations do generically not have solutions for the undifferentiated variables $x^\rho$ and $x_\sigma$.

It's simpler, and possibly has less content, than you think.
Staring from
$$
\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^\nu} = \delta^\mu_\nu
$$
where $\delta^\mu_\nu$ is the Kronecker delta, you just multiply both sides by $g^{\nu\sigma}$ to raise the $\nu$ index
$$
g^{\nu\sigma} \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^\nu} = g^{\nu\sigma} \delta^\mu_\nu 
$$
or
$$
\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x_\sigma} = g^{\mu\sigma}
$$
where we've used a common convention that $g^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu \phi = \partial^\mu \phi$ -- this is just a convention of what it means to raise/lower the index of a partial derivative, that the raised index partial derivative usually means that the metric acts "to the left" of the derivative, and is not itself differentiated.
The partial derivative isn't a tensor in a curved manifold, of course. We aren't raising and lowering indices on a tensor, we are just defining a useful convention for what $\partial^\mu$ means. There is no more content in the equation in your question than the first, trivial equation in my answer. In particular, you can't use $\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x_\nu}=g^{\mu\nu}$ to calculate the metric, since to calculate $\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x_\nu}$ you need to know the metric to begin with.

Yes, it's precisely that "common convention" that I was hoping to prove, using known definitions. Since the metric exchanges covariant and contravariant coordinates $x_\mu$ and $x^\mu$, there must be a "rigorous" demonstration?

@KhunChang It's a definition. You can't prove it. However, it is not equivalent to the version where the $g_{\mu\nu}$ moves to the right hand side of the derivative, ie it's not the case that $\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^\nu} = \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial(g_{\nu\sigma} x^\sigma)}$. It just turns out that the expression $g^{\nu\sigma} \partial_\sigma x^\mu$ (with the $g$ out side of the derivative) comes up more frequently than $\frac{\partial}{\partial (g_{\nu\sigma} x^\sigma)}$ in practice, so it is worth developing a shorthand notation for the former but not the later.

In particular, "raising the index on $\partial_\mu$" is not some kind of covariant statement about tensors. It is only a shorthand defined for convenience. In fact I actually don't like using it because it can be confusing, I'd much rather only use $\partial_\mu$, which has an unambiguous meaning, and explicitly include metric factor acting on non-tensor objects like $\partial_\mu$ as appropriate.


On one hand, the standard notation in GR is that spacetime coordinates $x^{\mu}$ are endowed with a superindex; not a subindex. E.g. the (0,2) metric tensor is related to arc length as
$$ (ds)^2~=~g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu} dx^{\nu}. $$

On the other hand, a spacetime coordinate with a subindex is then by definition
$$ x_{\mu}~:=~g_{\mu\nu}x^{\nu}, $$ which is not a very useful concept outside of SR.

It seems OP's notational convention is precisely opposite. Translating OP's title expression into the standard notation, OP wants to consider
$$\frac{\partial x_{\sigma}}{\partial x^{\nu}} ~=~\frac{\partial[x^{\mu}g_{\mu\sigma}]}{\partial x^{\nu}}~=~g_{\nu\sigma}+x^{\mu}\frac{\partial g_{\mu\sigma}}{\partial x^{\nu}}, $$
so OP's title equation is in general not true.

Let us for completeness mention that
$$ \partial_{\mu}~:=~\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}$$
and
$$ \partial^{\mu}~:=~g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu},$$
so that
$$  \partial^{\mu}x^{\nu}~=~g^{\mu\nu}.$$



"so OP's title equation is in general not true." That's wrong; the assertion is correct. See the very simple proof below.
